# Access the $form_state and get data from it

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I am working on a Drupal troubleshooting session while I went through the code I found the following code:

```
$rpms = $form_state->get(['storage', 'rpms']);
```

Then I found

```
$rpm_selected = $form_state->getValue('rpms');
```

And I do not have experience with Drupal, so is there a difference between the 2, or the 2 are similar, and this is a clerical error or a verbose code

Answer (score 3):

To get the form values, you must use:

```
$rpm_selected = $form_state->getValue('rpms');
```

Storage is usefull to save custom variables to recover in the future, example:

```
// set data
$form_state->setStorage(['my_custom_var' => 'test']);

// get data.
$vals = $form_state->getStorage();
```

Comment: Commenting on your response and quoting from it "To recover the values from your form I recommend to use... etc.", this means that the two lines in my question express one thing, which is obtaining a field value from the Form. This means that I can comment one of them and rely on the second?

Comment: If you save your form values in your storage you can recover from there. If you didnt, you must recover from the getValue function. I m going to change the answer to be clear.

Comment: This is with regards to the purpose of using Storage I mean are both $rpms = $form_state->get(['storage', 'rpms']); And $rpm_selected = $form_state->getValue('rpms'); identical?, which means that I can only use one and comment the second, taking into account that both statements are for data recovery, and they do not include saving data for later use. Rather, it is only restored.

Comment: You cant recover the form values from Storage $form_state->get(['storage', 'rpms']) its functionality is for other things. Check the url for more information https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/class/FormState/8.2.x . Use $form_state->getValue("xxx").

Comment: What do you mean by the "You cannot recover the Form values ​​from the Storage"? Also what do you mean by "its functionality is for other things"? Are the Form values ​​stored in a different place other than Storage. The problem with the Drupal documentation, I find it is insufficient and does not give complete data on the parts placed on it, or data that largely clarify the purpose of each part that is placed there. Thanks a lot for your time and interest in helping me appreciate it :)

Comment: $form_state->getValue() returns the (processed) values the user typed into the form in the browser, whereas $form_state->get() returns values from the forms storage. You can use this to store any data to it's available in your form handlers.